# Protocol not working

Tags: objective-c, protocols

It's a pretty stupid mistake, I'm sure, but I can't find it.
What I've found is mostly that one has forgotten an `#import` line.
I did not.
I'm very new to objective-c, and tried protocols, but I got 8 errors now...
I'm pretty sure it is the protocol, because there are 2 errors in my protocol, and all other errors say 'can't find protocol definition' what I thought was caused by the errors in the protocol.
Here's the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CongTile.h"


@protocol TileDelegate

- (UIColor *)colorForTile:(CongTile *)tile; // Expected ')' before 'CongTile'
- (BOOL) drawArmyOnTile:(CongTile *)tile; // same error

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try losing the `#import "CongTile.h"` in favour of `@class CongTile;`

If you use `#import`  and both file's end up importing each other you create an import loop.

---

### Side note

Assuming that any class that implements `TileDelegate` will be a descendant of `NSObject` you may wish to declare your protocol as

```
@protocol TileDelegate <NSObject>
```

this way the compiler knows that any time you use `id<TileDelegate> delegate` in your code the object will respond to `<NSObject>`

Comment: +1 exactly. Try to reduce the inclusion of headers within other headers as much as possible by using forward declarations as drafted.

Comment: For example if you don't add `<NSObject>` then you will get a warning if you try to call `respondsToSelector:` on an object declared as `id<TileDelegat>`